# signal strength in linux

Tags: ubuntu

I am able to read the signal strength from the iwconfig command but how do I take the value of signal strength only i.e -94 dBm. I run my command like this where i only need the bold values to be printed or written to another file so that I can compare the RSSI.

```
root@dibya-notebook:~# iwconfig wlan0 | grep Signal         
 Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=**-51** dBm

root@dibya-notebook:~# iwconfig wlan0 | grep dBm
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=**-48** dBm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iwconfig | awk -F'[ =]+' '/Signal level/ {print $7}'
```

Comment: thanks but this still didn't work because i get nothing.   I tried this                                                        root@dibya-notebook:~# iwconfig wlan0 |   awk '/Signal level/ {print $4}' and I get level=-61 but still i am unable to separate only -61 from this. how can i use the field separator for awk.

Comment: i could do it using the cut command.iwconfig wlan0 | awk  '/Signal level/ {print $4}'|cut -c 7-9
-84                                                                                                                                        Thanks Barmar

Comment: When you originally posted the question, you didn't format the output properly, so I didn't see that there's a variable number of spaces between fields. See the updated `awk` comment.